# Postgresql indexing a range type

Tags: postgresql, indexing, date-range

I have an table which has an `daterange` column. I want to select rows that contain date of today.

`select * from mytable where drange @> now()::date`

the `@>` operator is true if range [contains element](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE)

indexing of range types is made with the [GiST index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/rangetypes.html)

so I created an index `CREATE INDEX my_idx ON mytable USING gist (drange)`

but `explain select * from mytable where drange @> now()::date` always returns

```
Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..1051.82 rows=26104 width=38)
   Filter: (drange @> (now())::date)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index is good; probably the condition is not selective enough for PostgreSQL to choose the index.

You can lower the parameter `random_page_cost` to make PostgreSQL decide more in favor of an index scan.

I'd suggest that you perform a couple of test runs with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` with a sequential schan as it is now and then a few with `random_page_cost` set to a lower value (1, 1.5 or 2) to make PostgreSQL choose an *index scan* or a *bitmap index scan*. Then you'll see which option is the fastest – it might be the sequential scan after all.

Beware that running a query several times will cause the data blocks to be cached, which may lead to unrealistically good results. You should compare performance on a “cold” cache, which you can simulate by restarting the PostgreSQL server (and/or emptying the operating system's file system cache).